# Geospatial query error in NodeJS Mongoose Mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying my hands at geospatial queries in Mongodb. So far it's pretty cool, but I've run into a wall.

I was successfully able to create a 2dsphere index, and successfully able to do a $near query from the MongoDB CLI, but when I try and do the query from Mongoose in NodeJS, I get a strange error.

here's the code I run in NodeJS:

```
var query = model.where('loc').near({ center: [50, 50], maxDistance: 5000 });
query.exec(function(err, myModel){
   if(err){console.error(err);}
    res.json(myModel);
});
```

This gives me the error: **[Error: Can't use $maxDistance with String.]**

So I tried running my original query that works in the MongoDB CLI:

```
model.find({loc: {"$near": {"$geometry": {"type": "Point" , "coordinates": [ 50 , 50 ]},"$maxDistance": 500,"$minDistance": 0}}},function(err,myModel) {
        if(err){console.error(err);}
        res.json(myModel);
    });
```

And I get a similar error: **[Error: Can't use $near with String.]**

From what I've found from looking around the interwebs, it looks like it might have something to do with how mongoose parses the data and passes it to MongoDB, but I'm not entirely sure. I'm basing my queries off the ones I found here:
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-near
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/

Any ideas for tackling this error would be appreciated!

Comment: They are actually different commands. You probably want `$near` under a `.find`()` most of the time unless you want the distance for some purpose. And even then I would generally recommend the aggregation `$geoNear`, since you usually want a distance field for some further use or calculation.

Comment: Thank you Neil, using geoNear worked! I'll probably just use that. Though I'm still curious as to why those sample queries did not work...

Comment: The `.near()` method implemented in mongoose uses an older command syntax for which the $near operator more or less succeeds. The `.geoNear()` method does much the same thing with a "geoNear" command syntax which is still reasonably valid. Aggregate `$geoNear` is a "boosted" version of that command syntax. Main point is geospatial is still somewhat evolving, and things are a bit more stable now than they were.